# How to print multi selected rows of dataset (Delphi, Fast report)

Tags: delphi, fastreport

Delphi 10.4.2, Fast Report 6.

I use TFDQuery and TDbGrid components.

TDbGrid options: RawSelected,MultiSelected, AlwaysShowSelection=true

RangeBegin and RangeEnd of FrxDbDataset=rbCurrent.

If I select, for example, 3 rows (left ctrl+mouse) then SelectedRows.Count gets value 3 (as breakpoint shows) but is printed columns of only one row (last in numbering selected row in dbgrid). How to print columns of all  selected rows? Is it possible without memtable or clientdataset?

```
 query1.sql.text:='select * from datailtable where mastertable_id=:id';
 query1.open;

 dbgrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected:=true;

 for i := 0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 Do Begin
    DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);
 end;

 frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'Doc_id.fr3');
 frxReport1.PrepareReport;
 frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

**UPDATE. solution**:

```
var str, sSql, s: string; 
Query1.filtered:=false;
sSql:='select * from datailTable where  Master_id=:id';
for i := 0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count-1 Do Begin
           DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);
           s:=s+','+inttostr(DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger);
          end;
delete(s,1,1);
         
str:='ID in('+s+')';
Query1.filter:=str;
Query1.filtered:=true;
frxReport1.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+'Doc_id.fr3');
frxReport1.PrepareReport;
frxReport1.ShowPreparedReport;
```

RangeBegin must be rbFirst, RangeEnd- reLast.

Comment: if I know well; because you set up the "reCurrent" at both settings
"RangeBegin - rbCurrent – from the current record RangeEnd  - reCurrent – till the current record" it will show only the current which is the last selected in this case.
I am not sure you can print only the selected rows without a"filter", but you can use a memory table and insert the selected data to the memory table and use the memory table as the source

Comment: @Tamas , If I choose rbFirst  and reLast then it selects and prints all rows of dataset. I would prefere without memory table if it is possible.

Comment: if you use the "reCount" you can print the number of row, but I can't see any option to print only the selected so far. If you don't want to use a memory table, you can filter the dataset and set up the "rbFirst"-"reLast"  before the print.